# Scheduled messages, emails, reminders

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to know what is the best way to plan for scheduled messages, emails and other stuff. For example if I have appointments listed in my web application, I want application to send users email before appointment and at the time of appointment. There can be 1000 emails to be sent at once because of large user pool.

Please suggest what are the best possible ways to achieve that and if there is a service (paid/free third party) where I can post my scheduled tasks and it should do the work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any services that do this "out there" but the best way if you were developing it would be to create a Windows Service which runs on a timer, say every 10 minutes or so.

it would read from the database appointments up coming within the next 15 minutes or 30 minutes by a SQL Query. 
Once data is returned, you would create a timer for possibly each one of those records which then is set to fire off at the right time via the timer tick event for that appointment. 
Once the timer ticks, you simply send the email on a threadpool to avoid the main thread being held up/being blocked when sending out a batch of emails and to make your service a bit more responsive.

you cannot do this "automation" in ASP.NET and a Windows Service is exactly for this purpose where you have a regular interval to do a task - in this case, to get a list of appointments/schedules for a period of time and then send an email.

once the email is sent, you need to update that record to ensure it is not picked up again in the next timer event to avoid duplicate emails being sent - a flag like "SentReminder" being set in the field of your record in the database.

this is how to do it and is the best way.